# Does `sshfs -o allow_root` open any security holes? Why isn't allow_root enabled by default?

Tags: linux, security, sshfs, fuse

> allow_root
>
> This option is similar to allow_other but file access is limited to the user mounting the filesystem and root. This option and allow_other are mutually exclusive.
>
> From mount.fuse(8)

If the platform matters, assume that I'm on the latest version of FUSE and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

When you use this option, you're giving the system administrator(s) of this machine access to your files on the remote server, which they wouldn't have if they don't have their own accounts on that server.

But since root has access to everything on this client machine, they don't really need your permission. They can use `su` to changed to your userid, and then they'll be able to access anything you can access.

So this just makes things easier for the superuser. This is useful if you're the sole user of the machine, so `root` is really yourself, and you want to be able to access your SSHFS filesystems while using `sudo`.

Comment: I haven't studied the problem in depth, but I have the hunch that the existence of the `allow_root` option is an accomodation made for sudo-maniacs rather than anything else -- they were trying to use `sudo command /path/to/remote/file` directly, failed, so this option was added to make them happy.

Comment: It probably makes sense for single-user machines, where root is essentially the same user. Although then `allow_other` is also reasonable.

Comment: In other words, it gives users a false sense of security. Root doesn't care about your private key or password; root can just login as you with `su` and access your mounted FUSE filesystems. Dunno why you mention keyloggers.

Comment: I was thinking about root mounting your filesystem without you, so it would need your SSH credentials, but that's not what this is about.

Comment: root access for sshfs is possible the way shown here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99492/226127 for ssh access: root w/o password, key only can access; then sshfs can mount root@address without the "-o allow_root"(!) and without the "-o default_permissions" but I need to give "-o allow_other" to sudo on the sshfs mounted file system as root.   Don't forget the weird "fusermount3 -u /mnt/mymountpoint".   Yes, works. Ubuntu 20 and 22 basis.